# Unable to sort the character array using bubble sort in C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, char, bubble-sort

I am trying to sort an array of characters in C but it prints out the same array instead of the sorted

```
char*P[5] = {"1c", "4h", "3g", "10g"};
total_items = 4; // number of elements in the array. 

for(int q =1; q<total_items; q++)
{
    for(int k=0; k<total_items-q; k++)
    {
        if((int)P[k]>=(int)P[k+1])
        {
            temp=P[k];
            P[k]=P[k+1];
            P[k+1]=temp;
        }
    }
}
```

When I print out the array, it's the same as the original. I tried debugging by printing in the if statements; it turns out it never enters the swap block of the code. Is there something I am missing?

The expected output should be 1c, 3g, 10g, 4h.

Comment: Use `strcmp` instead of `>=` (`>`).

Comment: @BLUEPIXY : Hi, would you be able to edit this for me? I tried using strcmp and it prints out the whole array in the opposite order, not sure where I am going wrong here :\

Comment: Read [strcmp](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp)

Comment: @StackOverflow You should be able to write the condition based on the return value of strcmp.

Comment: @Mahesh : could you please edit my solution and post it as an answer?

Comment: If you are trying to sort by numeric part, try `if(atoi(P[k]) > atoi(P[k+1]))`. (`atoi` in `#include <stdlib.h>`)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY : No the whole string it is, so it should out 1c, 3g, 10g, 4h. Instead my out is the reverse order of original when I use strcmp :\

Comment: Do you want a sort on character part? And for the same letter, order by numerical value. In that case `strcmp` can not be used. You need to create your own comparison part that way.

Comment: Please edit the question and add a description of the sort order you desire. not comment.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY : any clues or hints on how to do it ?

Comment: Separate numbers and letters and determine the order.

Answer (score 1):

Create your own comparison function.

like this :

```
int cmp(const char *a, const char *b){
    int ai, bi;
    char ac, bc;
    sscanf(a, "%d%c", &ai, &ac);//Separate number and letter
    sscanf(b, "%d%c", &bi, &bc);
    if(ac > bc)
        return 1;
    else if(ac < bc)
        return -1;
    return ai < bi ? -1 : ai > bi;
}
```

then Replace `if((int)P[k]>=(int)P[k+1])` with `if(cmp(P[k], P[k+1]) > 0)`

Comment: Hi, thank you so much. Just another point of enquiry, the code fails when I try to run it with different array such as {1a 1c 2a 2f 1d}, it outs 2a 1d "whitespace" 2f.  Any idea to why?